# Python Can metavar of argparse option be accessed?

Tags: python, argparse

I was wondering if there was a way to use the metavar from argparse be grabbed from elsewhere.  Example, there is a -f FILE option, and a -d DIR option. Can I make the help of -d grab the file.metavar or some such?
Maybe:

```
 parser.add_argument("-f", "--file",
          metavar = 'FILE',
          action="store", dest="file_name", default="foo.bar",
          help="Name of the {} to be loaded".format(metavar))
parser.add_argument("-d", "--dir",
          metavar = 'DIR',
          action = 'store', dest='file_dir', default=".",
          help="Directory of {} if it is not current directory".format(option.file_name.metavar)
```

I know this code is wrong (string doesn't have metavar and options doesn't get set until the parser.parse_args() is run), but I have a few other times I want to just grab the metavar without having a bunch of:

```
 meta_file = 'FILE'
 meta_dir = 'DIR'
 meta_inquisition = 'SURPRISE'
```

floating around.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** s/add_option/add_argument/

Comment: I don`t think so. There is a bunch of questions asking to use the 'default' arg in 'help'. And there is no how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `argparse` it is [`add_argument()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument).  This method returns an `Action` object (actually a subclass of that depending the `action` parameter).  You can access various parameters of that object, either to use, or even change.  For example:

```py
action1 = parser.add_argument(
    "-f",
    "--file",
    metavar = "FILE", 
    dest="file_name",
    default="foo.bar", 
    help="Name of the %(metavar)s to be loaded"
)
action2 = parser.add_argument(
    "-d",
    "--dir",
    metavar="DIR", 
    dest="file_dir",
    default=".", 
    help="Directory of %s if it is not current directory" % action1.metavar
)

print(action1.metavar)  # read the metavar attribute
action2.metvar = "DIRECTORY"  # change the metavar attribute
```

The `help` reads:

```
usage: ipython [-h] [-f FILE] [-d DIR]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f FILE, --file FILE  Name of the FILE to be loaded
  -d DIR, --dir DIR     Directory of FILE if it is not current directory
```

I removed `action="store"` since that is the default value (no big deal though).

I changed the `help` values to use `%(metavar)s`.  This is used to incorporate various `action` attributes.  Most commonly it is used for the `default`.

From the `argparse` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#help):

> The help strings can include various format specifiers to avoid repetition of things like the program name or the argument default. The available specifiers include the program name, %(prog)s and most keyword arguments to add_argument(), e.g. %(default)s, %(type)s, etc.:

I am using `action1.metavar` to place `FILE` in the help line for `action2`.  It's not a common usage, but I don't see anything wrong with it.

Note that `action1.metavar` is used once when setting up the parser (to create the `action2` help line), and then later when the `help` is formatted.

```
In [17]: action2.help
Out[17]: 'Directory of FILE if it is not current directory'    
In [18]: action1.help
Out[18]: 'Name of the %(metavar)s to be loaded'
```

`py3` style formatting can be use for `action2`:

```py
help2 = "Directory of {} if it is not current directory".format(action2.metavar)
action2.help = help2
```

but `py2` style has to be used for `action1`.  Unless you did:

```py
action1.help = "Name of the {} to be loaded".format(action1.metavar)
```

After creating both actions you even could use:

```py
action1.help = "Name of the {} to be loaded from {}".format(action1.metavar, action2.metavar)
```

But that's just ordinary Python coding.

Comment: this looks promising. I will run through it with my stuff.  Also thanks for the add_argument.  Still stuck using optparse in my brain.

Comment: Shame that it does not work for the default `metavar` calculated from `--my-option`: you have to explicitly give `metavar=`. Python 3.6.5.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs for the `help` argument](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#help), the help text can contain format specifiers like `%(default)s`, `%(type)s`, etc. You can write `%(metavar)s` and it will be expanded to the value of the metavar (or `None` if it's not specified).

I don't think there's a way to grab another's argument metavar.

Comment: Note the importance of `s` after `%(metavar)`, I didn't get it when reading the docs.